# Приставка не- с глаголами

Tags: орфография

Прочитала правило:"Не" пишется слитно:
В глагольной приставке недо-, обозначающей несоответствие требуемой норме, например:
недовыполнить (выполнить ниже требуемой нормы),
недосмотреть (недостаточно, плохо смотреть, упустить что-нибудь), недосыпать (спать меньше нормального).

Примечание.
От глаголов с приставкой недо- надо отличать глаголы с приставкой до-, имеющие впереди себя отрицание "не" и обозначающие не доведённое до конца действие, например:
не дочитать книгу, не допить чай, не досмотреть пьесу.

Вопрос: о ведь существует слово "досмотреть", к нему получается это правило не применимо?. Т.е. несмотря на наличие приставки до- "не" всё равно пишется с ним слитно?

Answer (score 1):

Вы совершенно верно сформулировали правило, в том числе привели примеры с глаголами "недосмотреть - не досмотреть". Вот еще пример: Производится досмотр автомобиля. Проверяющие не досмотрели багаж  до конца и в результате недосмотрели провоз запрещенных предметов.

И еще другие, более интересные примеры. Живая русская речь украшает нашу жизнь, создает приятное настроение. Поэтому предлагается почитать русскую классику для праздничности:

Замечаю, брат, что ты приуныл; говори прямо: чего тебе недостает? (А. Пушкин).

Еще кого недосчитались вы? (А. Пушкин).

Он жил скупо; недоедал, недопивал, одевался бог знает как. (А. Чехов).

И как недосмотрел! И как недослышал! (А. Грибоедов).

Она не дослушала, отошла прочь. (А. ТОлстой).

Высоко стоит луна, даже шапки не докинуть. (С. Есенин).

Клевещущих козлов не досмотрел я драки, Как петушок в прозрачной летней тьме (О. Мандельштам)

Словно бывши на спектакле, Пятый акт не досмотреть И уйти… куда? — во мрак ли, В свет ли яркий?.. Мысль, ответь! (В. Брюсов)

Comment: В приведённом вами примере:"Проверяющие не досмотрели багаж до конца и в результате недосмотрели провоз запрещенных предметов." в на мой взгляд совершенно идентичных словах "не досмотрели - недосмотрели" не- употреблено и слитно и раздельно. Почему?

Comment: Нет сочетаемости "досмотреть провоз", обычно производится досмотр вещей. ДОСМОТР(спец.).  Проверочный осмотр.  Таможенный  д. НЕДОГЛЯДЕТЬ, НЕДОСМОТРЕТЬ.     Проявить  недостаточное  внимание, оплошность при наблюдении, проверке. Н. за ребенком. Н. опечатки.